# Increment based on the first numbers in a string

Tags: delphi, increment

I really hope you understand what i'm trying to do ^^

So i have a function which is supposed to increment a number. I give a string to this function which is a string based on several number. For example myfunction("64");

My purpose is to increment this string like this:

> 641
>   642
>   643
>   ...
>   6410
>   6411
>   6412
>   ...
>   6421
>   6422
>   ...
>   6431
>   6432
>   ...
>   64110
>   64111
>   ....
>   64220
>   ...

or

> 641
>   6410
>   64100
>   6411
>   64111
>   64112
>   64113
>   ..
>   64119
>   6412
>   64120
>   64121
>   ...
>   and so on until 64999.

So far here is my logic:

```
procedure tForm1.IterateEveryPossibilities(c: String);
var
   cLength: Integer;
   i,j: Integer
   sI: String; 
begin
   cLength : Length(x); //This is the length of the string
   for i : cLength+1 to 5 do // maximum length of the number is 5. there's no number over 99999
   begin
      for j := 0 to 9 do // adding 0 , 1 , 2 , ... 9 to the number
      begin
        si := c + intToStr(j);
      end;
     C := sI;
   end;
  end;
```

I tried to get how much number I have to add and just adding 1,2,...9 aat the end. But it doesn't try the number like 11 12 13 it just goes 641 642.... 649 and then 6491 6492 6493, and don't tries 6410 6411.

Can you help me? I can't find the logic for this one :/

Thanks

Comment: `uses Math ... for j := 0 to Trunc(Power(10, 6 - Length(c))) - 1 do ...` where `Trunc(Power(10, 6 - Length(c))) - 1` = 9999 for 1-char input, 999 for 2-chars input and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understod you question correct the this should do the trick for you :

```
function IterateEveryPossibilities(c: string): string;
const
  Min = 1;
  Max = 999;
var
  Buffer: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Buffer := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Buffer.LineBreak := ' ';

    for i := Min to Max do
      Buffer.Add(c + IntToStr(i));

    Result := Buffer.Text;
  finally
    Buffer.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That's perfect ^^ Not exactly what I did in my final solution but the Min and Max was what i should have thought about first. Thank you sir.